# jar mismatch, fix your dependencies

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i've created a new android application project and i got error as soon as it was created.

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
Versions found are:
Path: /asuspc/workspace/appcompat_v7/libs/android-support-v4.jar
    Length: 349252
    SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
Path: /asuspc/workspace/USCConverter/libs/android-support-v4.jar
    Length: 337562
    SHA-1: 27c24d26e4c5d57976e6926367985548678e913c
```

then i searched for answer and some people say i should delete android-support-v4.jar from libs folder and use only one.
when i deleted it from USCConverter project it wasn't solved.
then i restored it and deleted from appcompat_v7 and now there is no any error.
but i'm afraid will this mess something up?
i don't feel like deleting files would solve a problem.
and sorry if this sounds stupid, but i'm kind of newbie, what is this appcompat_v7 anyway?
and how come projects i created before didn't have this error, even though they had android-support-v4.jar as well?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove `android-support-v4.jar` from your project , clean it and if any error appeared, try adding it from your SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue arises when you have different versions of v4 library inside of your other libraries that you are using in your app, the simplest solution is to copy the v4 library from one of them and then put it in all of your libraries and don't forget to delete the old ones first

Answer (score 3):

I have same proplem. I was working about Facebook with login my application. Solition is : Just kidding. You may see people advice you to delete one of the support jars from your project but this really not solving the problem right way. Eclipse is screaming cause both jars shuld have same checksum, to do that you have to get the latest support jars for both projects. Eclipse have tools for that when you right click your application.

**1-Your Project right click / Android Tools / Add Support Library**

Answer (score 0):

You have to go in your project properties , than androids and in library remove `android-support-v4.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by simply deleting the file android-support-v4 from the path similar to yours.

ie : /asuspc/workspace/appcompat_v7/libs/android-support-v4.jar

this problem usually arise whe you copy your projects in workspace from one location to another.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic problem.
In eclipse you can add jars in multiple ways :

1> Go to file location of jar (C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\recyclerview\libs) and copy the jar and paste it into the libs folder of your project. 
Right Click on jar in libs folder **->** Build Path **->** Add To Build Path.
Now, Right Click on project **->** Properties **->** Java Build Path **->** order and Export => check all the jar you copied.

2> Create a library project of desired jars
go to your project -> right click -> properties -> Android -> (In Library region) Add.. -> select newly created library project -> Ok -> Ok

the problem arises when you use both this approach to add the libraries and there are version conflicts in both this approach.

I removed libraries added using second approach and the problem got resolved for me.
Go to Project -> Right click - > properties -> Android -> (In library Region) select your custom library project -> Remove -> Ok

Removing libraries this way might impact other functions of your project as this library project might contain multiple jars.